# listbox ItemsSelected in ms access

Tags: ms-access, listbox, ms-access-2010, criteria, listboxitem

I have a form contains of 3 listboxes that will filter my report based on the selected items
in my query I used the below criteria for the combobox and I tried it on the listbox but it does not work!

```
Like [Forms]![Statusfrm]![FieldCombo] & "*"
```

any advise please?

[image]

[image]

I also tried this but when I select one selection it is not showing records for the same selection!

```html
Private Sub Command26_Click()
   On Error GoTo ControlError
   Set ctl = Me.Combo22 'frm!Combo22
   Set ctl2 = Me.Combo24
   
   'Set rpt = Foms!rpt
   
   If Me.Combo22.ListIndex <> -1 Then  'And Me.Combo24.ListIndex <> -1
      miFiltro = "id in("
      For Each varItm In ctl.ItemsSelected
       'miFiltro = miFiltro & "'" & varItm & "',"
       miFiltro = miFiltro & varItm & ","
       'Lista27.AddItem varItm
     
       'ctl.ItemData (varItm)
    
      Next varItm
   
      miFiltro = Mid(miFiltro, 1, Len(miFiltro) - 1)
      miFiltro = miFiltro & ")"
      'MsgBox (miFiltro)
      If miFiltro <> "" Then
       DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt", acViewPreview, , miFiltro
       miFiltro = ""
      End If
      
     'Aplicamos el filtro al formulario
     'Me.Filter = miFiltro
     'Me.FilterOn = True
   Else
     MsgBox ("Please select data")
     Me.Combo22.SetFocus
   End If
     
   'DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt", acPreview, , Me.Filter
   

ControlError:
    MsgBox "Encontré el error" & Err.number & " " & Err.Description
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Where's the code for View Report? Where's the Report's recordsource or query SQL? What does "it does not work" mean? Error or bad results?

Comment: Try opening the report manually (from the DB container). Access will prompt for that value, so try to enter a string to see if that works. If it does, the reference to the form is not available to the reports RecordSource when as it is loading (i.e. the form has closed). You can also change the report to use a query, and you can manipulate the QuerDef's SQL before you DoCmd.OpenReport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your Report to be based on a fixed DB query. When the user clicks the "View Report" button, add the code:

```
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE [Place] = '" + Me!Statusfrm + "'" 
CurrentDB.QueryDefs("TheAccessQueryObjectTheReportIsBasedOn").SQL = strSQL 
    
DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReport"
```

In this model, you are setting the SQL of the Query object at the Access DB container level, then opening the report. You can debug your VBA code more easily this way, instead of relying on a RecordSource query with a runtime parameter referencing the form. You can also close the form if you want to before opening the report.

The WHERE condition for your strSQL variable can be built up based on input (or lack thereof) from the user. For example:

```
If Nz(First(Me!categoryListBox.SelectedItems).Value,"") <> "" Then
   strSQL = strSQL + " AND [Category] = '" Me!categoryListBox.SelectedItems).Value + "'"
End

If Nz(First(Me!placeListBox.SelectedItems).Value,"") <> "" Then
   strSQL = strSQL + " AND [Place] = '" Me!placeListBox.SelectedItems).Value + "'"
End
```

Also, is your list box bound to an ID or the text of the item selected? You may be getting an ID vs the text you are trying to use with the asterisk wildcard. A list box can have multiple selections, so you need to disable it, or do something like :

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE [Place] = '" + First(Me!statusfrm.SelectedItems).Value + "'"
```

If the user can only select one value, a combobox it the better choice. Either way, by building up an SQL statement in VBA that uses the forms value, you can debug the syntax of the SQL more easily.

Comment: thank you very much, but I have multiple list boxes and I want them optional means if the user selected only one it will show the report based on his selection

Comment: Yes, this is why I recommended that you create a SQL string in VBA code, build it up based on the user selections (or lack of), and then apply it to the QueryDef. So you can have If statements that check for values in the form, and if they exist, modify the strSQL accordingly. I'll add an example in my response.